# jsonwebtoken.verify with Firebase SDK

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, jwt, firebase-authentication

I’m using `jsonwebtoken` on the server with node and this to verify client requests (firebase 2.x sdks):

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
jwt.verify(token, <firebase_secret>, (err, decoded) => { })
```

This works with requests from browser firebase javascript 2.x and ios firebase 2.x.

Now, we’re upgrading our ios sdk to firebase 3.x and verifying the token fails with this error: `[JsonWebTokenError: jwt malformed] name: 'JsonWebTokenError', message: 'jwt malformed'`.

What I want to do is the following:

- use browser firebase 2.x
- use ios firebase 3.x
- use node firebase 2.x

Is there a way to get the `jwt.verify()` to play nice with tokens that come from both browser 2.x and ios 3.x ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out token signing algorithms and private keys changed between Firebase SDKs 2.x and 3.x

- Node Firebase SDK for 2.x is called firebase-server
- Node Firebase SDK for 3.x is called firebase-admin

The solution I reached is by requiring both libraries on the node server and having 2.x clients send the token with one key, and having 3.x clients send the token with another key.

On the server-side - either decode with the firebase-server library or the firebase-admin library, depending on which token was sent. This allows us to upgrade the iOS SDK without also updating the web SDK at the same time